# Upgrading old Crystal Reports project to Visual Studio 2010 problems

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have to update and old VB project made with Visual Studio 2005 that uses Crystal Reports to Visual Studio 2010. I've installed the Crystal Reports plugin for VS 2010. I can compile the program under VS 2010 but when I run it and try to generate a report I get many errors popping up from the Crystal Reports Viewer. When I compile and run the project in Visual Studio 2005 (with the old Crystal Reports plugin that comes with it) everything works fine.

The problem is caused by SQL Expressions that are SELECT statements that are not enclosed in parenthesis. This is a problem because there are ~250 SQL Expressions like that in the report file (and it's not the only report with this problem). When I look at the .rpt file in Crystal Reports 10 and use `Database -> Show SQL Query` the SQL Expressions have parenthesis around them despite there being no parenthesis around these statements in the SQL Expression Editor. When I do the same in Crystal Reports 2008 the SQL Expressions don't have the parenthesis included.

Is there a way to make Crystal Reports 2008 or the plugin in for VS 2010 automatically include the parenthesis around SQL expressions, or was this feature removed? If it was removed, is there anyway to enclose the SQL expressions in parenthesis other than
editing each one manually?

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to automate what you describe.

Have you tried opening the RPT files in a later version of Crystal Reports and doing a Database, Verify Database to see if it would "autofix" the SQL Expression issue?